# Service Temporarily Unavailable

Tags: magento-1.9

I have installed an extension and return to my admin panel.

I got this error :

> Service Temporarily Unavailable. The server is temporarily unable to
>   service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems.
>   Please try again later.

How can i solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove main **maintenance.flag** from root directory of your site which have been created by magento itself for security reasons

if **maintenance.flag** is present in your root directory then you will be redirected to **/errors/503.php** by default

Answer (score 1):

You will find a `maintenance.flag` file in root of Magento directory. Just delete this file and try

Answer (score 1):

Remove the maintenance.flag flag to return to normal. In root directory.

Comment: thank you i have delteted maintanance.flag file and  Solved this problem

Comment: ok. welcome. Can to tick the answer right.